# Splitting a range into X groups

Tags: arrays, ruby, split, range

I need to split a range into X number of groups and I am having difficulties finding a way without using arrays since these ranges can be very large.

My current solution is to create an array out of the range and then call `each_slice` on it with some math to split the data into X number of groups more or less the same size depending on how many groups there are.

```
irb(main):026:0> a = (0..10)
=> 0..10
irb(main):027:0> a.each_slice( (a.size/3.0).round ).to_a
=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
irb(main):028:0> a.each_slice( (a.size/5.0).round ).to_a
=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10]]
```

The problem with this is that when a range is excessively large the application will hang because of the computation it takes to split the array.

All I really need is an array in this format (taking the a.size/3.0 3 group example into account):

`[0..3, 4..7, 8..10]`

So I may iterate the array to pass them to the `set_range` method in the `Net::HTTP` library.

The ranges I am dealing with are as large or larger than `0..46000000` since I am dealing with file sizes in bytes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
def split_ranges(amount, max)
    (0...amount).collect{|i| (i * max / amount)...((i+1) * max / amount)}
end

p split_ranges(3, 46000000)
```

Output:

```
[0...15333333, 15333333...30666666, 30666666...46000000]
```

Edit: (OP request)

```
def split_ranges(amount, max)
    (0...amount).collect{|i| (i * (max + 1) / amount)..((i + 1) * (max + 1) / amount - 1)}
end

p split_ranges(3, 46000000)
```

Output:

```
[0..15333332, 15333333..30666666, 30666667..46000000]
```

Comment: Yes this is more or less it, but the next begin value of the next index should be +1 of the previous indexes max value.

Comment: Never mind, I noticed you used the three dot `...` operator which excludes the last value of the range. This solution works, thanks. Although if it is simple enough to convert to the two dot notation adding that would be nice.

Comment: I noticed that if I set max to 3, and amount to 410739302 this method takes a while to return the results. It even returns a NoMemoryError failed to allocate memory error in IRB.

Comment: You switched the parameters around. There should be no appreciable speed difference between my method and Jason's. (Mine can handle ranges that don't start at zero, and actually work on a range; but that is not relevant to speed.)

Comment: @Amadan Thank you rotating my numbers around worked wonderfully. The naming of the variables confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Range
  def each_subrange(n)
    return to_enum(:each_subrange, n) unless block_given?

    range_size = size
    range_begin = self.begin
    n.times do |i|
      yield range_begin + range_size * i / n .. range_begin + range_size * (i + 1) / n - 1
    end
  end
end

a = 0..46000000
# without a block
puts a.each_subrange(3).to_a
# with a block
a.each_subrange(3) do |r|
  puts r
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert this into a function that does not modify the Range class or is this how it gains its performance? Comparing this answer to Jasons, this one produces the result instantly for file size 410739302 while his takes a while to compute (probably because of the 0...amount creating an array).

Comment: Sure, you can convert to a standalone function. Change `each_subrange(n)` to `each_subrange(range, n)`, and put in `range_size = range.size` and `range_begin = range.begin`. The rest should be fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that no range differs in size by more than one from the size of any other range:

```
def split_it(r, n)
  return [r] if n == 1
  last = r.first - 1 + (r.last-r.first+1)/n
  [r.first..last].concat(split_it(last+1..r.last, n-1))
end

r = 0..46000000

split_it(r, 3)
  #=> [0..15333332, 15333333..30666666, 30666667..46000000] 
split_it(r, 3).map(&:size)
  #=> [15333333, 15333334, 15333334] 

split_it(r, 4)
  #=> [0..11499999, 11500000..22999999, 23000000..34499999,
  #    34500000..46000000] 
split_it(r, 4).map(&:size)
  # => [11500000, 11500000, 11500000, 11500001] 

split_it(r, 5)
  #=> [0..9199999, 9200000..18399999, 18400000..27599999,
  #    27600000..36799999, 36800000..46000000] 
split_it(r, 5).map(&:size)
  #=> [9200000, 9200000, 9200000, 9200000, 9200001]
```